# What am I doing wrong in RegularExpressionValidator on a Multiline Textbox with Validation Expression?

Tags: regex, multilinestring

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="EmailLinkValidator" runat="server"
     controltovalidate="TextBox1" display="Dynamic" 
     ValidationExpression="?m:(^(?:(?:<a )?href|</a>\r?\n?)+)" 
     cssclass="clsError" errormessage="<%=this.ERR_MSG%>">*
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I am trying to validate the Multiline textbox to check if the value entered has any matching string as `HREF` or `href` or `<A HREF` or `<a href` or `</A>` or `</a>`. If so I need to give an error message. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I updated it with

```
ValidationExpression="(?m:(^(?:(?:<a )?href|</a>\r?\n?)+))"
```

Comment: In every lecture or tutorial I give on Regex, I always stress that you need to validate your Pattern against multiple expected inputs, both correct and incorrect.  Could you please provide a couple correct and incorrect inputs that you expect so I could advise you?  However, based solely on what I THINK you want, you'll do {a[^>]*href[^>]*>}.  Also, it appears your third example included an HTML Delimiter, so it isn't showing up.  Be careful with that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have an in-line `m` *multi-line* mode `(?m: modifier grouping)` that has its outside parentheses cut off. Try:

```
ValidationExpression="(?m:(^(?:(?:<a )?href|</a>\r?\n?)+))"
```

Comment: @Suamere - Basically I have a multiline textbox where we can enter HTML tags. But I should not allow the user to enter any links inside this textbox. I am doing the sanitize for regular HTML tags. But does not check for any HREF tags. So if the user is entering any HREF tags then I should stop them from entering. So I am presuming that the User would enter: <a href or <a HREF or <A HREF or </a> or </A>. Hope this helps. Please let me know.

Comment: This is still not working. It is possible that my HREF tag is in the middle and not just at the beginning..

Comment: Can someone please help. Thanks